# Spring Boot RequestMapping Delete does not work

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http, methods

1. The RequestMethod Delete does not work,  I tried it the same way
   with POST and it worked. The code is without DAO, it is only in
   Controller. In the following is the code. If I try to open the
   webpage, it shows that the  methods is not allowed ( Error 405). Can
   anyone say where the mistake is? Thank you in advance!

```
static {
        pokals.add(new Pokal("1", 1, "Deutscher Meister"));
        pokals.add(new Pokal("2", 5, "Deutscher Pokalsieger"));
        pokals.add(new Pokal("3", 1, "Uefa Cup Sieger"));
        pokals.add(new Pokal("4", 1, "Deutscher Zweitligameister"));

    } 


@RequestMapping(value = "/pokalList/{ID}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void deletepokal(@PathVariable("Id") String Id) {

        pokals.remove(Id);

    }
```

Comment: Probably calling as a GET not a `RequestMethod.DELETE`, unless you are using jquery or something.

Comment: can you add POST method in your sample code , controller annotations too

Comment: The above code is fine(except the PathVariable Id which is in different case, but that shouldn't be a problem since you'd gave got different error _Missing URI template variable 'Id'..._), since you're getting 405 it's likely your issue in the way you access this API. How are you accessing this ? If you can use curl, can you try this and let us know what is the error `curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:8080/pokalList/1`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks alright.

> If I try to open the webpage, it shows that the methods is not allowed ( Error 405). Can anyone say where the mistake is? Thank you
>   in advance!

However, from the statement above in your question, you seem to imply that you tried to access the endpoint as a webpage via your browser?

The browser sends a GET request which is not be allowed as a DELETE is expected hence a 405 status.

Trying using CURL to send a DELETE request:

```
curl -iv -X "DELETE" http://localhost:8080/pokalList/1
```

or using a client such as postman

Comment: How different this is from my comment above, if may I know?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With curl it doesnt work also. Do you mean I need to implement jQuery AJAX?

Comment: @SevLarry What response do you get when using curl? Is it still a 405?

Comment: @k.wahome No i  didnt get error 405. If I type curl localhost:8080/pokalList/2 or  curl -iv -X localhost:8080/pokalList/2 they shows google search results.

Comment: You mean typed on the browser? Yeah that is going to result in a web search

Comment: curl is a command line tool i.e you install and invoke it from your command line terminal